# I'm using BufferedReader to input string values into the Excel file but in the next iteration it's skipping the entry of the first string

Tags: java, file-handling

This is the code I have written. It works fine when I use `Scanner` but doesn't work properly with `BufferedReader`.

**This is the Question**

Develop and test a program according to the following specification.

- Consider a class Student with instance fields name, registration number and CGPA.
- Enter information about twenty such students through keyboard into an Excel file.
- Sort the records of the file in order of registration number.
- Split the content of the file into two halves and write each half to an Excel file.

Code:

```
package com.hitesh;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Student {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("DA3.xls");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String name;
        String registrationNo;
        float gpa;

        int n = 0;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        fw.write("Student Name" + '\t' + "Registration No" + '\t' + "GPA" + '\n');
        while (n < 3)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter Student Name: ");
            name = br.readLine();
//            name = scanner.next();
            System.out.print("Enter registration number: ");
            registrationNo = br.readLine();
//            registrationNo = scanner.next();
            System.out.print("Enter GPA: ");
            gpa = br.read();
//            gpa = scanner.nextFloat();
            fw.write(name + '\t' + registrationNo + '\t' + gpa + '\n');
            n++;
        }
        fw.close();
    }
}
```

[Output Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sakj.png)

Comment: First off: the question is badly defined. An "Excel file" is a *binary* file, to write which, you'd need a special API. You *can* write to a csv file, which is a text file, and will *open* in Excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine for me – JDK 11 on Windows 10 – after I changed this line of your code:

```java
gpa = br.read();
```

to this:

```java
gpa = br.readLine();
```

According to the *javadoc* for method [read](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read()), in class `java.io.BufferedReader`:

> Reads a single character.

The newline in Windows is actually two characters so you are actually just reading one character in the last part of the `while` loop and ignoring the newline characters which messes up the first `readLine` call in the beginning of the next iteration of the `while` loop.

Here is the complete code.

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Student {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("DA3.xls");
             InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
             BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr)) {
            fw.write("Student Name" + '\t' + "Registration No" + '\t' + "GPA" + '\n');
            int n = 0;
            while (n < 3) {
                System.out.print("Enter student name: ");
                String name = br.readLine();
                System.out.print("Enter registration number: ");
                String registrationNo = br.readLine();
                System.out.print("Enter GPA: ");
                String gpa = br.readLine();
                fw.write(name + "\t" + registrationNo + "\t" + gpa + "\n");
                n++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And Excel correctly displays the file – after it shows me a dialog window with a message that the file format is not suitable and asks me whether I still want to open the file. I say yes and the data written to the file in the Java program is correctly displayed. Of-course Excel guesses how to display the data which meant that it did not display the GPA correctly. In order to create a correctly formatted Excel file from Java, you need to use a library like [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I would `Scanner` as you planned:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("DA3.csv");
        final String FMT = "%s\t%s\t%s%n";

        String name;
        String registrationNo;
        float gpa;

        int n = 0;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        scanner.useDelimiter("\\R");
        fw.write(String.format(FMT, "Student Name", "Registration No", "GPA"));
        while (n < 3) {
            System.out.print("Enter Student Name: ");
            name = scanner.next();
            System.out.print("Enter registration number: ");
            registrationNo = scanner.next();
            System.out.print("Enter GPA: ");
            gpa = scanner.nextFloat();
            fw.write(String.format(FMT, name, registrationNo, gpa));
            n++;
        }

        fw.close();
    }
```